# Is there a way to manually edit my Windows -> Run command history?

Tags: windows-7

Windows 7.  I rely on my Windows -> Run command box regularly throughout my work day.  However, I occasionally mistype a command, and this command gets stuck in the auto-complete history.  This is particularly annoying when the mistype makes the wrong command precede the correct version in the command history.  At this point I end up always executing the wrong command once before realizing I have to play closer attention to what was being listed and manually locate the correct version.

I don't want to clear the whole thing, because then I would lose the history of the useful commands.  I just need to get rid of the irritating ones that get in the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Windows XP, 7 and 11 this is stored in the registry under:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU
```

From there you can remove or edit the ones that you don't need.
I don't have any computer with Vista/Windows7 so I can't confirm if this is the same key for Windows 7.

**UPDATE:** You will need to restart your computer for the changes to take effect, since they are stored in memory.

Comment: Yes, it is the same on Windows 7, and I assume Vista as well.

Comment: Thank you so much, that did the trick.  Will give you the green check as soon as the accept-answer timeout is over.

Comment: Didn't have to reboot here - change was instant.